# Can't pass a data object to view controller inside a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm not sure why, but I'm having trouble passing a data object (NSManagedObject) to a view controller when that view controller is being instantiated inside another one. When I log the object before it is passed, it has all of its data, but after it gets to the view controller, it is empty. It seems like this should be fairly straight-forward, but for some reason it's just not getting there.

The code which assigns the NSManagedObject to the accepting view controller in the implementation file is: viewController.thisCard = aCard;

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the header for the view controller which scrolls:

```
@interface HandViewController : UIViewController 
<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

    BOOL pageControlIsChangingPage;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

/* for pageControl */
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;

@end
```

this is the viewDidLoad in the implementation of that object

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Game" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedGames = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [fetchRequest release];

    Game *aGame = [fetchedGames objectAtIndex:0];

    CGFloat cx = 0;

    for (Card *aCard in aGame.turnUpcoming.hand) {

        CardViewController *viewController = [[CardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CardViewController" bundle:nil];

        CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
        rect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height - 50;
        rect.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width - 50;
        rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - rect.size.width) / 2) + cx;
        rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - rect.size.height) / 2);
        viewController.view.frame = rect;
        viewController.thisCard = aCard;
        [scrollView addSubview:viewController.view];

        cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;

        [viewController release];
    }

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [aGame.turnUpcoming.hand count];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

UPDATE: Per request, I am adding a bit of code from the view controller

This is the header for CardViewController

```
@interface CardViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardValue;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardInstruction;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardHint;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardTimer;
    UIButton IBOutlet *playCardButton;

    Card *thisCard;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardInstruction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardHint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton IBOutlet *playCardButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Card *thisCard;

@end
```

Here is the viewDidLoad from the implementation of CardViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     if ([thisCard isObjectValid]) {
        cardValue.text = [thisCard.value stringValue];
     }

}
```

UPDATE: new code for card loop in viewDidLoad and new CardView code, per suggestions below

loop in viewDidLoad:

```
for (Card *aCard in aGame.turnUpcoming.hand) {

        CGRect rect = scrollView.frame;
        rect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height - 50;
        rect.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width - 50;
        rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - rect.size.width) / 2) + cx;
        rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - rect.size.height) / 2);

        tempCardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        tempCardView.thisCard = aCard;

        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardView" owner:self options:nil];

        tempCardView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        [scrollView addSubview:tempCardView];

        cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;

        [tempCardView release];
    }
```

header file CardView.h

```
@interface CardView : UIView {
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardValue;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardInstruction;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardHint;
    UILabel IBOutlet *cardTimer;
    UIButton IBOutlet *playCardButton;

    Card *thisCard;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardInstruction;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardHint;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel IBOutlet *cardTimer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton IBOutlet *playCardButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Card *thisCard;

@end
```

implementation file CardView.m

```
@implementation CardView

@synthesize cardHint;
@synthesize cardTimer;
@synthesize cardValue;
@synthesize cardInstruction;
@synthesize playCardButton;
@synthesize thisCard;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        if ([thisCard isObjectValid]) {
            cardValue.text = [thisCard.value stringValue];
            cardInstruction.text = thisCard.instruction;
            cardHint.text = thisCard.hint;
            cardTimer.text = [thisCard.time stringValue];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

UPDATED: 6/16 - Added XIB screen shot

CardView.xib

[image: CardView.xib]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your CardViewController should actually be a UIView.  As Apple says: " A single view controller typically manages the views associated with a single screen’s worth of content, although in iPad applications this may not always be the case."

(After changes to UIView) in your loop, you're creating one tempCard and then loading another.  If you've linked tempCardView in IB (see below), then all you need is:

```
for (Card *aCard in aGame.turnUpcoming.hand) {
    CGRect rect;
    rect.size.width = scrollView.frame.size.width - 50;
    rect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height - 50;
    rect.origin.x = ((scrollView.frame.size.width - rect.size.width) / 2) + cx;
    rect.origin.y = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - rect.size.height) / 2);
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CardView" owner:self options:nil];  //magically connected to tempCardView.
    self.tempCardView.frame = rect;
    self.tempCardView.thisCard = aCard;

    [scrollView addSubview:tempCardView];
    cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.tempCardView = nil;
}
```

So, you have two XIBs, your main one that loads with your viewController, and one (CardView) that gets loaded once for each card.

Now, inside CardView, you're trying to set up the labels too soon. During initWithFrame (which in the above case is called by loadFromNib), you don't have access yet to thisCard.   You'll need a setter for thisCard, which will be called any time a value is assigned to thisCard property:

```
   -(void) setThisCard: (Card *) newCard {
       if (thisCard == newCard) return;
       [newCard retain];
       [thisCard release];
       thisCard = newCard;
       self.cardValue.text = [thisCard.value stringValue];
       self.cardInstruction.text = thisCard.instruction;
       self.cardHint.text = thisCard.hint;
       self.cardTimer.text = [thisCard.time stringValue];
    }
```

Now in Interface Builder,

1. Create CardView.xib with a single UIView with, but set FileOwner to your VC, NOT to CardView because that's who's going to load it (and who has the tempCardView property).
2. Set the view's type to CardView, then hook it to thetempCardView property of FileOwner (aka HandViewController)
3. Put all your other card parts inside that CardView and hook them up to that CardView's properties.

You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm going to try changing it to a UIView and see what happens. I will post the results when I am finished.

Comment: So, if I manage the subviews using a UIView, as opposed to a UIViewController - is there a way to do this where I can use a nib file to control the several objects within the UIView? It would make life much simpler if I didn't have to code out the layout of all the objects within the subview. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, in fact, you can have views within views in your nib file for the VC.  But I assume you want a variable number of them in your example. In this case, you can load one with loadNibNamed:owner:options: Set owner to your VC, but have a tempCardView property defined in your VC, which is linked to the view you create in IB.  Now in viewDidLoad, call loadNibNamed and tempCardView will be linked to a new CardView.  Hand it an aCard, link it to your view, release your copy (as the superview retains it), and then do it all again.

Comment: Just saw your edits.  As I suspected, you're assuming that aCard is assigned before viewDidLoad is called on your CardController.  But your previous reference to viewController.view.frame magically loads your view for you, so VDL is called BEFORE you assign aCard.  Simply swapping those two lines would probably fix your original problem.  Nonetheless, it's MUCH better to replace your cardVC with a cardView.  Put the displaying code in that view, but keep the game code in the main VC, sending messages to the views (presumably kept in an NSArray) as needed.

Comment: Thanks very much for the additional info. I'm having some difficulty following, though. I'm trying to do it the right way, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. if I replace my cardVC with a cardView, should I do that as a subclass of UIView?

Comment: I don't think I'm quite following what yo're saying - posting the code for a UIVIew subclass called CardView and the code I have right now for the viewDidLoad in the main VC.

Comment: Ok - I'm trying to implement the last suggestion as it seemed to be the one I should try. I think the problem may be how I have tempViewController and CardView.xib defined. I currently have an XIB file for the main controller (HandViewController.xib) which is where this viewDidLoad code we've been looking at resides. That XIB has a scrollView and pageControl - I have since placed another UIView inside the scrollView and assigned that UIView to tempCardView. I'm not sure how CardView.xib is getting into tempCardView - I see the magic you've described, but XCode doesn't recognize...

Comment: ...that the Outlets (cardValue, cardInstruction, etc) belong to tempCardView.

Comment: Right, forgot about tha.  Yes, you need to keep your custom UIView, but really it just needs the CardView.h file with nothing but synths in the.m (unless you like the theCard setter trick if you're assigning new cards at other times).  So...(1) take your CardView.xib, but set FileOwner to your VC, NOT to your view (2) add a top-level view and set its type to CardView, then hook it to FileOwners tempCardView property (3) put all your other parts inside CardView and hook them up to CardView's properties.  Now when you load a Cardview.xib, tempView will be set and all its parts will be set.

Comment: To clarify from your last note: you do not need a tempCardView in the main NIB, only in the one loaded for each card.

Comment: ok - it's still not recognizing the tempCardView as having the properties - I"m assuming when you say "tempCardView hooked into FileOwner" that you are referring to assigning a referencing outlet in IB from the view to tempCardView - correct?

Comment: I'm posting a screen shot of the CardView.xib up above - perhaps we can pinpoint what I am missing

Comment: Almost there. That's correct on the tempCardView hookup, but you don't have part 3: the CardView outlets hooked to the subviews. In the upper right, those outlets need to be connected to each of the objects under the CardView on the left hand side. For example, cardHint to Label-Hint. Also you have an extra View hanging around at the bottom there.

Comment: That did it! When you said "Add a top level view and set its type to CardView" above I thought you meant to add an additional view - that's why that extra view was hanging around. And I had each of the label fields hooked up to IBOutlets in that view instead of what you indicated in your last comment. All set and working!

Comment: Great. I've updated my note above (and simplified your title for others having the issue). Hope things go easily from here.